# Nullable reference types, Hint static analysis that parameter is never null

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Lets say I have this extension method

```
 public static TRes Map<TSource, TRes>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TRes> mapper) 
        {
            return source is null ? default : mapper(source);
        }
```

usage:

```
myobject.Map(obj=> new OtherType(obj,1,2,3));
```

I get a warning that `obj` can be null. Is there any way, in the declaration of my extension method, that I can hint static analysis that obj cannot be null, since `mapper` will not be called if `obj` is null.

I dont want to use ! everywhere, preferably never

Comment: this is on an object, not a IEnumerable/collection. This is just an example, dont take the use too seriously

Comment: [Repro](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAbhATgSxgTwD4ACATAIwCwAUAMRgCuANvQIbD0QAEEYLbllBAZnbF2AYUoBvSuxnChBACzsAsgAoAlNNlSKsvexRN07ALY4A9sABWEAMZR2AXnaQA7uwDK5kxAAqOAAcIDQBuLX1TC2s7KAA6ZSYA1UsrJwA+Fwh3AHkoAAsMfyDk6wQSBCIEAXV1MN1ZAF9KJop+eSJPbz9Ajgl2FsFhDtyC9CKISXCZQZHCntUvH3H2AGcu8YR2TDAHRC2d9hxN7YcAL3V2PobZZr4KQYISADYh9gBROCguFcxzMBXJvVpvJnuxfAAlCArFSJAA8vi8tHQtggmwhULSqnymGhCPMSJRq3xyNRwgArPDESS0ZCVhkTIkgugLlMdBFpgB2IkEjg4lwMejsAD87AAJhAYEwGA4QKZGRhVGsebUptcZM0gA==). You'll only get a warning inside `Map` itself, because it can return null. If you don't want this, don't return null

Comment: in this case myObject is source in the extensionMethod, and if source is null, the mapper() will not be called (ie the lambda), Map will just return null. so if the lambda is executed, the obj will not be null. So its not about the return value ...

Comment: So you want to return `TRes?`? :)

Comment: See my link. The only warning in that code is inside `Map`, warning that it can return `null` even if `TRes` is a non-nullable type. E.g. `foo.Map<FooType, string>(...)` can return `null`, even though the `string` parameter says that it cannot return null

Comment: again, its not about the return value about the lambda/mapper. Its about if source/obj is null or not.

Comment: I have given you a sharplab link which shows where the only warning is. It is not warning that the `obj` parameter to the delegate can be null. If you are seeing something different, please post a link to sharplab which actually demonstrates your issue

Comment: Or did you mean [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAbhATgSxgTwD4ACATAIwCwAUAMRgCuANvQIbD0QAEEYLbllBAZnbF2AYUoBvSuxnChBACzsAsgAoAygHsAthAAqOAA4QA/O205NwAFYQAxlACU02VIqyP5yzftQAdMpMhqpW1uwAvAB87JAA7uwA8lAAFhgGxiE2COwk2UTZAo6OANwuMgC+lJUU/PJE7Fq66RwS7NWCwvVJqejNkmUyHd1pRhAaOvqj7ADOE83ZmGBQ7Ijsi8s4C0vsAF6O7K3lslV8FB0EJABsnewAonBQXNOYmmDT/e6y51fsegBKEGmKiCAB49FpaOg7BBsv9AZFVClMEDwZpIdCZmioTDhABWMEQ7GwgHTaLaILGdD7AZuTxfADsmPRHGRMQY9HYZgAJhAYEwGMsQOYKRhVLNmSUBkcZFUgA==)?

Comment: @canton7: yes, but you instantiate myObject on the line above. It should hold even if myobject is set to null (without getting a warning)

Comment: @canton7, yes, like that :)

Comment: Right. This is why including a [mcve] is important

Comment: [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAbhATgSxgTwD4ACATAIwCwAUAMRgCuANvQIbD0QAEEYLbllBAZnbF2AYUoBvSuxnChBACzsAsgAoAygHsAthAAqOAA4QA/O205NwAFYQAxlACU02VIqyP5yzftQAdMpMhqpW1uwAvAB87JAA7uwA8lAAFhgGxiE2COwk2UTZAo6OANwuMgC+lJUU/PJE7Fq66RwS7NWCwvVJqejNkmUyHd1pRhAaOvqj7ADOE83ZmGBQ7Ijsi8s4C0vsAF6O7K3lslV8FB0EJABsnewAonBQXNOYmmDT/e6y51fsegBKEGmZkChgAPHotLR0HYINl/oDIqoUphpr9IdDTDNNFCYdkCABWcHo3G/AHTaLaILGdDOT4yNyeL4AdixOI4KJiDHo7DMABMIDAmAxliBzFSMKpZmySgMjjIqkA==).

Comment: We declare the `TSource? source` parameter as nullable, which lets `TSource` be inferred as `SomeType`, even when `Map` is called on a variable of type `SomeType?`. This flows into the `Func`: since `TSource` is `SomeType` (not `SomeType?`), we promise that the `Func` will never be called with `null`. We also return `TRes?`, to say that we can return `null` even if the signature of the `Func` says that it cannot return `null`

Comment: ok, seems to work.Great, thanks!!!
But since Im using <C#9 I need to add "where TSource : class"

Please add your answer (and preferably the "where TSource : class" for us slow adapters, in an answer, so I can set that as correct answer.

Thanks again

Comment: You can still use attributes pre-C#9, but annoyingly they don't impact the inference of `TSource` as non-nullabe, so they don't particularly help. I think I've got another idea, putting together an answer now...

Comment: The following page from Microsoft lists multiple attibutes (like NotNullWhenAttribute, MemberNotNullAttribute, ...) that may be of interest to those coming to this question
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

1. `Map` can be called on `null`.
2. Even if `Map` is called on `null`, the `Func` parameter will not be called with a `null` input
3. `Map` can return `null`, even in cases where the `Func` does not return `null`

Put this together, and:

```
public static TRes? Map<TSource, TRes>(this TSource? source, Func<TSource, TRes> mapper)
{
    return source is null ? default : mapper(source);
}
```

The `TSource? source` means that even if we call `Map` on a variable which may be `null`, `TSource` is still inferred as non-nullable. This means that the `Func<TSource, TRes>` will not receive `null` as its input.

The `TRes?` means that we're allowed to return `null`, even if `TRes` is inferred as nullable (from the signature of `mapper`).

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAbhATgSxgTwD4ACATAIwCwAUAMRgCuANvQIbD0QAEEYLbllBAZnbF2AYUoBvSuxnChBACzsAsgAoAygHsAthAAqOAA4QA/O205NwAFYQAxlACU02VIqyP5yzftQAdMpMhqpW1uwAvAB87JAA7uwA8lAAFhgGxiE2COwk2UTZAo6OANwuMgC+lJUU/PJE7Fq66RwS7NWCwvVJqejNkmUyHd1pRhAaOvqj7ADOE83ZmGBQ7Ijsi8s4C0vsAF6O7K3lslV8FB0EJABsnewAonBQXNOYmmDT/e6y51fsegBKEGmZkChgAPHotLR0HYINl/oDIqoUphpr9IdDTDNNFCYdkCABWcHo3G/AHTaLaILGdDOT4yNyeL4AdixOI4KJiDHo7DMABMIDAmAxliBzFSMKpZmySgMjjIqkA==).

Pre-C#9, you are only able to use `?` on generic type parameters if you constrain them to be a reference or a value type: unconstrained `?` was only added in C# 9. You will need to add `where TSource : class where TRes : class` if you are using C# 8.

Comment: Thanks! As a bonus:
I run C# <9, this signature worked for me without any errors
[NEWLINE]
public static TRes? Map<TSource, TRes>(this TSource? source, Func<TSource, TRes> mapper) where TSource : class where TRes: class

Comment: Aha, maybe it's just the inference which changed in C# 9. Odd that adding `class` constraints fixes it...

Comment: in my case this also works , `public static TRes? Map<TSource, TRes>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TRes> mapper)` and `public void M(SomeType myobject)`

Comment: @Daniel That misses the point though: the warning only happens because `Map` is called on a type which might be `null`. See the comments on the OP, where I went through the same discussion

Comment: @canton7: just a final thing, mostly fyi. this is the error message Ive got (before adding constraint): 

CS8627 A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type unless language version '9.0' or greater is used. Consider changing the language version or adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

Comment: Aah right, so you're able to use `?`, but only if you constrain to a class or a struct. That makes sense -- I'd forgotten that an unconstrained `?` was a C# 9 thing, thanks! Updated my answer